# Twitter reverse auth doesn't work with account other than the one that owns the app

Tags: ios, twitter

I'm trying to implement Twitter reverse auth. I'm using Sean Cook's reverse auth implementation:
https://github.com/seancook/TWReverseAuthExample

And I've created a Twitter app on dev.twitter.com. The example code above works fine for the Twitter account I used when creating the app, but any other account fails with the error below:

```
<error code="89">Error processing your OAuth request: invalid signature or token</error>
```

Is there something I need to enable on my app somewhere? Googling around yields lots of suggestions to email Twitter and ask them to enable reverse-auth on my app, but more recent info says that it's now enabled by default for new apps.

Comment: nope, I can confirm that it worked on a new twitter app I created. It might be confusing but can you debug which token/secret is being sent with the request ?

Comment: I'm using my consumer key and consumer secret, which is what the settings are named in the plist file. Interestingly, when I do use app-owning Twitter account, on successfully completing the reverse auth I end up with my app's oauth_token and oauth_token_secret, which I also don't entirely understand - I thought the point of reverse auth is that a user can log in to Twitter, give my app read permissions, and then I get back a token which I can send to my server, which in turn sends _that_ token to Twitter and gets the user back. Have I misunderstood this?